# How do I Plot Polio Data as heatmap showing states on the y-axis and years on the Y-axis?

Tags: python, seaborn, visualization

I am currently trying to learn how to apply Data Science skills which I am learning through Youtube and other sites to little personal projects.

I found a dataset on Project Tycho from the US Department of Health and Human Services which includes all weekly surveillance reports of nationally notifiable diseases for all U.S. cities and states published between 1966 and 2013.

I exported the data to a .csv file and imported it into a Jupyter notebook which I am running through Anaconda. Currently, I'm making an attempt to visualize the cases of polio in each states across the years using the ** seaborn heatmap.**

However, the visualization I want never happens, I have conducted my research for answers which seems futile.

I tried the below:

```
polio_data=polio[['state', 'cases','incidence_per_100000','year']]
polio_years = list(polio_data['year'].unique())
polio_states= [v.title() for v in polio_data.state]
polio_data = polio_data.groupby('year').sum()
polio_data = polio_data.transpose().values

plt.figure(figsize=(12,12))
```

```
sb.heatmap(polio_data, cmap='Reds', robust=True,
      xticklabels=[year if year % 5 == 0 or year == max(polio_years) else '' for year in polio_years],
      yticklabels=polio_states)`
```

Result: attached image

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYKqE.png)

Was hoping for the below graph:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHpxc.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `polio_data` data frame has the following data:

```
,state,cases,incidence_per_100000,year
2,PA,0,0.0,1928
3,GA,1,0.03,1928
4,IN,1,0.03,1928
5,ME,0,0.0,1928
...
```

We can create a matrix for your heat map like this:

```py
polio_data_disp = (
    polio_data

    # Update `state` names as you did. e.g. PA --> Pa
    .assign(state=polio_data.state.str.title())

    # Need to group by `state` too, otherwise you'll lose state distinction
    .groupby(["year", "state"], as_index=False).sum("incidence_per_100000")

    # Use `pivot` to set `state` to the index and `year` to columns
    .pivot("state", "year", "incidence_per_100000")
)
```

We then pass this data frame to Seaborn.

```py
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 12))

sns.heatmap(polio_data_disp, cmap='Reds', robust=True,
    xticklabels=[
        x if x % 5 == 0 else ""
        for x in range(polio_data.year.min(), polio_data.year.max())
    ]
)
```

Then you should get the figure you wanted!